# How are you supposed to configure your keyboard?

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, 23.10

**How does one work out what specific keyboard hardware one has, and so what settings to use?** I use Kubuntu (23.10 mantic), so the keyboard settings ask for "keyboard model" first which is a list of things from "A4Tech | A4Tech KB-21" through to "eMachines | eMachines m6800 laptop" I can't recall any keyboard I ever had been on the list.

Then one has to select "layout", which has no descriptions but does provide previews -- but the previews don't match my keyboard(s).

I can use `xinput` and it lists my keyboard correctly, but the KDE keyboard settings aren't populated using that information (I don't think it's enough); the names aren't listed anyway.

So, for one particular keyboard I chose "generic 86-key" {counting it appears to have 88}, it's TKL (no number pad)**strong text** so it's probably not 105 ... am I supposed to sit and count the keys? All the same layouts are still listed (surely some of them don't match 86-key hardware?); after a few tries I chose "English (US, Euro on 5)" as luckily my keyboard has a € symbol on the 5. But this can't be how you're supposed to do it: try one of the 100 layouts until the test produces the right output -- notably the "preview" still doesn't match my keyboard, it has buttons missing, but thankfully those buttons work as expected.

Help says, "Modern keyboards that come with your computer usually have two extra keys and are referred to as '104-key' models". But I'm pretty sure I've never used the 104-key.

I must be doing this wrong? **What's the proper way to do this?** Maybe there is a database of keyboards and settings that work, or a website where I can choose which key is where and it tells me the hardware and layout settings to use??

FWIW, `xinput` recognises my keyboard on each install I have, but this doesn't seem to be used by Settings. I'm looking for the process to use, as I have different machines with different keyboards, and want to able to advise others how to input these settings correctly.

There are a couple of questions on this, but the [most recent is 8 years old](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422648/how-to-automatically-select-the-right-keyboard-layout-with-only-one-keyboard), things must have improved since then, surely?